# SSL Error after upgrading to Windows 8.1

Tags: google-chrome, windows-update, ssl, windows-8.1, ssl-certificate

After upgrade my Windows 8 to Windows 8.1, I got this SSL Error:

[image: SSL Error on Chrome]

...and this

[image: SSL Error on IE]

I have did some research and tried to change my system time up to date, reset my modem and use wireshark to see if anybody is tracking my network, but none of them seem to be the problem.

Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot...

**EDIT:**
I have checked my browsers and just figure out that every connection from my computer is not able to connect to any SSL connection, for example Yahoo Messenger login. I'm thinking my computer SSL Certificate got serious problem, is there anyway to "reset" it?